# нужен скрипт html для смены даты с определёнными условиями, код НЕ HTTP, а HTTPS

Tags: html

Необходим такой скрипт, чтобы дата менялась следующим образом: до 16:00 показывалась дата сегодняшнего дня, после 16:00 показывалась уже завтрашняя дата, код не HTTP, а HTTPS. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт вставлять в конец страницы перед

```
</body>
</html>
```

```
<p id="hours"></p>

<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var day = date.getDate();
    if (month == 0,3,5,7,9,11 && day >= 31) {month += 1;day = 0;} // Проверка для переходя на след. месяц 
    else {if (month == 2 && day >= 28) {month += 1;day = 0;} 
    else {if (day >= 30) {month +=1;day = 0;}}}
    if (hour < 16) {
     if(day == 0) {day = 1);}
        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    } else {

        switch (month) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " января";
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " февраля";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " марта";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " апреля";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " мая";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июня";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " июля";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " августа";
                break;
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " сентября";
                break;
            case 9:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " октября";
                break;
            case 10:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " ноября";
                break;
            case 11:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = day + 1 + " декабря";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, только на странице это показывается следующим текстом: "Sat Jan 30 2021 18:38:24 GMT+03:00, Москва, стандартное время). Можно исправить, чтобы отображалось так: "30 января", без текущего времени и года?

Comment: Конечно можно, момент

Comment: Дополнил, можно сократить, но я писал на скорую руку. Поэтому так. Возможно дополню уже сокращенным

Comment: а размер выходного текста как сделать побольше раза в 3, чем есть сейчас?

Comment: @АлинаВоропаева ну у тебя есть тег `<p>` у которого есть `id="hours"`. В файле где находятся все CSS стили, прописываешь
`#hours {font-size: 12pt; // Непосредственно сам размер шрифта}`